# Angular11 update, ng2-charts, Error: Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular11, ng2-charts, angular-upgrade

I am currently working on updating the angular version of a project. It was v10 and I updated to v11. Fixed many errors, but ng2-charts keep throwing these errors on ng serve.

```
Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/base-chart.directive.d.ts:39:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 
'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

39     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/base-chart.directive.d.ts:40:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 
'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration'.

40     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration, "canvas[baseChart]", ["base-chart"], { "type": "type"; "legend": "legend"; "data": "data"; "opti
ons": "options"; "plugins": "plugins"; "labels": "labels"; "datasets": "datasets"; }, { "chartClick": "chartClick"; "chartHover": "chartHover"; }, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:14:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵF
actoryDeclaration'.

14     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:15:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵN
gModuleDeclaration'.

15     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:16:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵI
njectorDeclaration'.

16     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFa
ctoryDeclaration'.

8     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:9:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵIn
jectableDeclaration'.

9     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/theme.service.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFact
oryDeclaration'.

10     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/theme.service.d.ts:11:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/projects/Credo/kratos/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInje
ctableDeclaration'.

11     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/modules/discussions/modules/view-discussion/view-discussion.module.ts:18:10 - error TS2724: '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member named 'ChartsModule'. Did you me
an 'NgChartsModule'?

18 import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:11:22
    11 export declare class NgChartsModule {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'NgChartsModule' is declared here.


Error: src/app/modules/statistics/statistics.module.ts:4:10 - error TS2724: '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member named 'ChartsModule'. Did you mean 'NgChartsModule'?

4 import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/ng-charts.module.d.ts:11:22
    11 export declare class NgChartsModule {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'NgChartsModule' is declared here.


Error: ./src/app/modules/discussions/modules/view-discussion/view-discussion.module.ts 48:16-28
"export 'ChartsModule' was not found in 'ng2-charts'

Error: ./src/app/modules/statistics/statistics.module.ts 32:16-28
"export 'ChartsModule' was not found in 'ng2-charts'

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 13:35-50
Can't import the named export 'BehaviorSubject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 118:6-11
Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 118:27-32
Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 120:34-39
Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 429:0-5
Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 433:93-98
Can't import the named export 'Chart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 228:11-24
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 270:12-25
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)0m

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 67:26-38
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 68:26-38
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 50:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 423:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-window-token/fesm2015/ngx-window-token.mjs 2:17-31
Can't import the named export 'InjectionToken' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 279:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 71:62-82
Can't import the named export 'distinctUntilChanged' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 429:47-60
Can't import the named export 'registerables' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 35:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 234:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 408:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 460:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 255:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 29:20-41
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 222:26-47
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 402:29-50
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 451:22-43
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 37:21-45
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 410:30-54
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 470:22-44
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 462:22-44
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

I tried many different versions of ng2-charts, chart.js and @types/chart.js, but nothing seems to fix it.

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "kratos",
      "version": "15.17.1",
      "engines": {
        "npm": "please-use-yarn",
        "yarn": ">= 1.22.4",
        "node": ">=12.17"
      },
      "license": "proprietary",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/credoweb/kratos.git"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && ng serve --disable-host-check --host 0.0.0.0",
        "start:ci": "yarn start --progress=false",
        "build": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
        "build:client": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
        "build:server": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run kratos:server:production",
        "build:ssr": "yarn build:client --deploy-url=//d34t42wpe6kclg.cloudfront.net/client/ && yarn build:server && gulp && yarn patch:manifest",
        "build:dev:ssr": "yarn build:client && yarn build:server && gulp",
        "dev:ssr": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run kratos:serve-ssr",
        "lint": "ng lint kratos && yarn lint:style",
        "lint:style": "stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" -q -o lint-report.json",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
        "check-permissions": "make check-permissions",
        "pm2:start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.json",
        "pm2:stop": "pm2 delete ecosystem.config.json",
        "pm2:restart": "pm2 restart ecosystem.config.json",
        "test": "ng test kratos",
        "test:ci": "yarn test --progress=false --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
        "test:e2e": "nightwatch",
        "test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test start:ci http-get://localhost:4200 test:e2e",
        "test:e2e:remock": "cross-env REMOCK=1 nightwatch",
        "test:e2e:nofixtures": "cross-env DISABLE_FIXTURES=1 nightwatch",
        "test:e2e:debug": "cross-env DEBUG=nock.* nightwatch",
        "test:e2e:lbo": "cross-env LEAVE_BROWSER_OPEN=1 nightwatch",
        "release": "cross-env HUSKY_BYPASS=true standard-version",
        "patch:manifest": "node patch-hashed-assets-manifest --deploy-url=//d34t42wpe6kclg.cloudfront.net/client/",
        "webpack:analyze": "yarn patch:pdpfjs && ng build --prod --statsJson=true && npx webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/browser/stats.json",
        "patch:pdpfjs": "node patch-pdf-worker.js",
        "patch:bootstrap": "node bootstrap-post-install.js",
        "postinstall": "yarn patch:bootstrap"
      },
      "private": true,
      "pre-commit": [
        "lint",
        "check-permissions"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-server": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/youtube-player": "^11.0.4",
        "@commitlint/cli": "11.0.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "11.0.0",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "5.0.8",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "10.1.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
        "@ngxs-labs/actions-executing": "^0.1.9",
        "@ngxs-labs/select-snapshot": "^3.0.0",
        "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.2",
        "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.7.2",
        "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.2",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
        "@types/chart.js": "2.9.37",
        "amazon-ivs-player": "1.2.0",
        "chart.js": "3.8.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "0.7.0",
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "datebook": "^7.0.8",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "hls.js": "^1.2.0",
        "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
        "husky": "^1.3.1",
        "isbot": "^3.4.6",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
        "mobile-detect": "^1.4.2",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "ng-in-viewport": "^6.1.5",
        "ng2-charts": "^3.0.11",
        "ng2-tooltip-directive": "~2.9.22",
        "ngx-captcha": "^8.0.1",
        "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
        "ngx-quill": "^13.2.0",
        "ngx-responsive": "^9.0.3",
        "ngx-uploader": "10.0.0",
        "pm2": "^4.4.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
        "quill-mention": "^3.0.3",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
        "standard-version": "9.0.0",
        "subsink": "^1.0.1",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.2",
        "video.js": "^7.11.8",
        "zone.js": "0.10.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.19",
        "@angular/cli": "11.2.19",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/service-worker": "^11.0.0",
        "@credoweb/phoebe": "0.0.13",
        "@hetznercloud/ngx-translate-mock": "^0.1.0",
        "@nguniversal/builders": "10.1.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.106",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
        "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
        "chalk": "^4.0.0",
        "chromedriver": "^85.0.0",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
        "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "detect-browser": "5.1.1",
        "dotdotdot-js": "4.1.0",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "gulp": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-hash": "^4.2.2",
        "http-server": "^0.10.0",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "~8.5.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "6.2.0",
        "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^5.0.1",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "9.1.0",
        "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
        "nightwatch": "^1.3.5",
        "nock": "^12.0.3",
        "proxy-chain": "^0.4.5",
        "querystring": "^0.2.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.6.3",
        "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.0",
        "stylelint": "^13.8.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "swiper": "^6.3.4",
        "ts-loader": "8.0.4",
        "ts-node": "9.0.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.1.6",
        "webpack": "^4.41.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
        "yargs": "^13.2.4"
      }
    }
```

angular.json

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "kratos": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/browser",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "showCircularDependencies": false,
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "assets": [
                  {
                    "glob": "config.json",
                    "input": "src/config",
                    "output": "/"
                  },
                  {
                    "glob": "**/*",
                    "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                    "output": "/assets/"
                  },
                  {
                    "glob": "**/*",
                    "input": "node_modules/amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/",
                    "output": "/assets/"
                  },
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/vendor",
                  "src/langs",
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
                  "src/e2e.html",
                  "src/legacy-index"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/core.scss",
                    "bundleName": "core",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/bootstrap-custom.scss",
                    "bundleName": "bootstrap.custom",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/shared.scss",
                    "bundleName": "shared",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/home.scss",
                    "bundleName": "home.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/publications.scss",
                    "bundleName": "publications.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/discussions.scss",
                    "bundleName": "discussions.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/events.scss",
                    "bundleName": "events.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/topics.scss",
                    "bundleName": "topics.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/surveys.scss",
                    "bundleName": "surveys.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/profiles.scss",
                    "bundleName": "profiles.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/notifications.scss",
                    "bundleName": "notifications.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/contacts.scss",
                    "bundleName": "contacts.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/settings.scss",
                    "bundleName": "settings.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/search.scss",
                    "bundleName": "search.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/chat-campaigns.scss",
                    "bundleName": "chat-campaigns.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/dashboard.scss",
                    "bundleName": "dashboard.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/referrals.scss",
                    "bundleName": "referrals.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/errors.scss",
                    "bundleName": "errors.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/static.scss",
                    "bundleName": "static.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/authentication.scss",
                    "bundleName": "authentication.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/courses.scss",
                    "bundleName": "courses.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/promotions.scss",
                    "bundleName": "promotions.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "src/styles/credoweb.scss",
                    "bundleName": "credoweb.chunk",
                    "inject": true
                  }
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  {
                    "input": "node_modules/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js",
                    "bundleName": "mutation-observer",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "node_modules/intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js",
                    "bundleName": "intersection-observer",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "node_modules/dotdotdot-js/dist/dotdotdot.js",
                    "bundleName": "dotdotdot-js",
                    "inject": true
                  },
                  {
                    "input": "node_modules/amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.js",
                    "bundleName": "amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min",
                    "inject": true
                  }
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": true,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "serve": {}
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "kratos:build:serve"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "kratos:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "kratos:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "karmaConfig": "./src/karma.conf.js",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles/main.scss"
                ],
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/vendor",
                  "src/langs",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.app.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            },
            "server": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/server",
                "main": "server.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
                "showCircularDependencies": false
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "serve-ssr": {
              "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "kratos:build",
                "serverTarget": "kratos:server"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "kratos:build:production",
                  "serverTarget": "kratos:server:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "prerender": {
              "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "kratos:build:production",
                "serverTarget": "kratos:server:production",
                "routes": [
                  "/"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "kratos-e2e": {
          "root": "e2e",
          "sourceRoot": "e2e",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "./e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "kratos:serve"
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": false,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "prefix": "app",
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true,
          "prefix": "app"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "defaultProject": "kratos",
      "cli": {
        "analytics": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this threat. After few days of going back and forth through versions, nothing worked at all. I decided to upgrade to angular 12, and it all started working again. No resolution for angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

Even same happened with me. After long time messing up with different versions finally I figured out compatible ng2-charts js veriosn for Angular 11.

Putting here for people who still struggling with above issue. Use below versions.
[image]